# Creating EventRelation over API

Tags: api, soap-api, related-list, event

I am trying to create and `EventRelation` over API, but I keep getting the following error even though I see `EventRelation` as available sObject and "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events" is enabled under Activity Settings in UI.

`Object type 'EventRelation' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.`

Is there something else I should enable or should I create these sObjects differently?

Comment: Are you using API 28.0? Its new and not supported in older api.

Comment: @dacology I haven't had time to make a full check, but you're right I wasn't using API 28.0. To start using it, I had to change WSDL endpoint for my SOAP requests to include '28.0' instead of previous version number. If you'll format this as an answer -> i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'EventRelation' object was introduced in the Summer 13 release and API version 28.0.

If your IDE is not updated you may be defaulting to a previous API version. 
If you are making direct calls to an endpoint such as rest or Soap you will need to update the url, for example:

Your Rest endpoint may be similar to:

```
$instance_url/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/EventRelation/
```

Your Soap endpoint may be similar to:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/28.0/
```